No sound from speakers and pluged in headphones Ubuntu 24.04.1
Laptop is MSI Raider GE78HX 13V.  There was sound when on 22.04, but one day it's gone, don't know why. I've tried to reinstall Alsamixer, Pipeware, Pulseausio, to restart services and have deleted desktop gui several times. There is indication that the sound is OK, but I hear no sound at all. Another thing I've found out is that there is no micro in settings. Using wireless earphones gives no problems. What else could I do?
$ inxi -SMA
System:
  Host: mikhail-Raider-GE78HX-13VH Kernel: 6.8.0-47-generic arch: x86_64
    bits: 64
  Desktop: GNOME v: 46.0 Distro: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: Micro-Star product: Raider GE78HX 13VH v: REV:1.0
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: Micro-Star model: MS-17S1 v: REV:1.0 serial: <superuser required>
    UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: E17S1IMS.111 date: 11/28/2023
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Raptor Lake High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: NVIDIA driver: snd_hda_intel
  API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-47-generic status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.5 status: active


you said you reinstalled pulse audio... do you have 'pulseaudio volume control' app installed. I found that it was a really good tool for working out what is going wrong and fixing it. even down to the app level.
you need to install 'gnome software' with the flatpak plugin and download the volume control as a flatpak.  It can check volume levels as a whole or at the app level to see if it is only on certain apps that there is a problem. You can then tweak the settings.
